# Clojure Quil: nested loops while drawing lines

Tags: algorithm, clojure, functional-programming, side-effects, quil

I'm having a serious problem with figuring out an algorithm in the Clojure Quil library. I've been trying to make some diagrams of networks/flocking patterns like [this](http://www.complexification.net/gallery/machines/happyPlace/) with the functional middleware mode. My question is how do you create a nested "for loop" in Quild in order to connect any given point to any other point with a line? The difference is between a set of points connected 1->2 3->4...etc and a set which is connected 1->2 1->3 1->4 2->3 2->4...etc.

My program looks something like this, though I've tried to edit it to be generic for the purpose of this question.

```
(ns stack-question.core
  (:require [quil.core :as q]
            [quil.middleware :as m]))   

;how to draw the point
(defn draw-points [point]
  (q/point (:x point) (:y point)))

;the main data structure
(defn make-point [num]
  {:name num
   :x (rand 500.0)
   :y (rand 500.0)})    

;draws connections between two objects
(defn connections [p1 p2]
      (q/stroke 200 200 100 150)
      (q/line (:x p1) (:y  p1) (:x p2) (:y p2)))))

(defn setup []
  (q/frame-rate 30)
  {:points (map make-points (take 1000 (range)))})

;this function isn't important to the question 
;but let's just say that the points move position each frame 
(defn update-state [state]
  (update state :points move-group))

;this is the problem function here.
;I'm trying to map over the collection, but with a fixed head
;and do so for each element in the collection
(defn make-conts [coll]
  (loop [x coll]
    (when (not (empty? (rest coll)))
      (map (partial connections (first x)) (rest x))
      (recur (rest x)))))


(defn draw-state [state]
  (do
    ;(q/frame-rate 1)
    (q/background 0)
    (doseq [x (map draw-point (:points state))] x)
    (doseq [x (make-conts (:points state))] x)))

(q/defsketch stack-question
  :title "GL"
  :size [500 500]
  :setup setup
  :update update-state
  :draw draw-state
  :middleware [m/fun-mode]
  :renderer :opengl)
```

I hope this isn't totally opaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

The first is that you are checking `(rest coll)` instead of `(rest x)` in the `when` statement, leading to an infinite loop.

The second is that `map` returns a lazy sequence, meaning that the calls to `connections` is not taking place. This can be fixed by wrapping the call to `map` with `doall`, but as you are interested in the side effects, not the return values, you should use `doseq` instead.

This version of the function (where the superfluous `loop` has also been removed) should work:

```
(defn make-conts [coll]
    (when (not (empty? (rest coll)))
      (doseq [endpoint (rest coll)]
        (connections (first coll) endpoint))
      (recur (rest coll))))
```

Instead of writing the code to generate the combinations yourself, you can use `combinations` from `clojure.math.combinatorics`:

```
(require '[clojure.math.combinatorics :as combi])

(defn make-conts [coll]
   (doseq [[p1 p2] (combi/combinations coll 2)]
     (connections p1 p2)))
```